# Is there a way to update/modify the scheduler entry in salesforce

Tags: scheduled-apex, scheduled-job

I've created a scheduler programmatically which runs everyday 12AM (`Cron expression : 0 0 12 * * ?`), but is there a way to change/modify the scheduler entry manually something like running `2 AM (0 0 2 * * ?)` instead of 12 AM.

Answer (score 1):

Once a record is created you can't modify it manually. But you can delete the old one and can create the new record.
To delete the old one
[image]

Add again.

```
System.schedule('Scheduled Job 1', '0 0 2 * * ?', new ScheduledClass());
```